# read textfile as formatted list

Tags: r, arrays, list, txt

I'd like to import a textfile as a list into R but don't know how to tell R the desired format. The source list is a txt file and is formatted as followes:

```
Column1=a
Date=21.01.2020
Column2=1|2|3
Subtable_Column1=a|2|3
Subtable_Column2=c|d|e

[2]
Column1=b
Date=21.02.2020
Column2=1|2|4
Subtable_Column1=a|2|3
Subtable_Column2=c|d|e
Subtable_Column3=c|d|e
```

In the end, each `[n]` should be the list index containing the named vectors (e.g. Column 1, Date etc.)
How's that possible in R?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to pre-format the data.

varval.dat

```
Column1=a
Date=21.01.2020
Column2=1|2|3
Subtable_Column1=a|2|3
Subtable_Column2=c|d|e

[2]
Column1=b
Date=21.02.2020
Column2=1|2|4
Subtable_Column1=a|2|3
Subtable_Column2=c|d|e
Subtable_Column3=c|d|e
```

It puts each dataset into a row of a data-frame:

```
awk -F '=' 'BEGIN{i=1}
!NF{i++; j=0; next}
/=/{ j++; cname[0,j]=$1; content[i,j]=$2; rows=i; cols[i]++ }
END{ m=0; for(k in cols){ if(cols[k]>m){ m=cols[k] } };
  for(j=1;j<m;j++){ printf("%s,",cname[0,j]) }; print cname[0,m];
  for(i=1;i<=rows;i++){
    for(j=1;j<m;j++){
      printf("%s,",content[i,j]) } print content[i,m] } }' varval.dat > varval.csv
```

R:

```
a <- read.csv("varval.csv", na.strings="")
#   Column1       Date Column2 Subtable_Column1 Subtable_Column2 Subtable_Column3
# 1       a 21.01.2020   1|2|3            a|2|3            c|d|e             <NA>
# 2       b 21.02.2020   1|2|4            a|2|3            c|d|e            c|d|e
```

I'm sure this is not exactly what you wanted but may serve as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for that! However, I'd like to use my code in a shiny app, reloading the df every ten minutes, so I'd rather exclusively use R. Do you have  recommendation?

Comment: If the output is useful it’s possible to do system calls and collect the results from within R. Pure R solutions might use readline to load the data and then subsequently format it with gsub and regular expressions. But that would need a bit more tinkering and a clear understanding of the whole workflow.